# Omnifaces CombinedResourceHandler -- Is there a way to suppress certain resources?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, omnifaces, combinedresourcehandler

I'm using Omnifaces 1.0 in conjunction with Richfaces 4.0. Typically, I suppress some of the css/js included by Richfaces as it's unnecessary and unwieldy. I do this by definiing a custom renderer for the renderer-type javax.faces.resource.Script or javax.faces.resource.Stylesheet.

When I enable org.omnifaces.resourcehandler.CombinedResourceHandler some of the previously suppressed CSS seems to be getting combined. Is there a way to define assets that I would like to have excluded from the ResourceHandler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature is not provided, but it is theoretically possible by supplying a special context parameter and changing the `CombinedResourceHandler` to exclude them from being combined.

Something like:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.omnifaces.COMBINED_RESOURCE_HANDLER_EXCLUDED_RESOURCES</param-name>
    <param-value>libraryName:resourceName1.ext,libraryName:resourceName2.ext</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Alternatively, another possibility would be to actually suppress them so that you don't need custom renderer to suppress them afterwards:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.omnifaces.COMBINED_RESOURCE_HANDLER_SUPPRESSED_RESOURCES</param-name>
    <param-value>libraryName:resourceName1.ext,libraryName:resourceName2.ext</param-value>
</context-param>
```

If you open a new feature request, then it will likely be implemented.

Comment: Great. I've opened one. Really love the project!

Comment: Yes, "Great Minds at work, making our lives easier and more efficient."

Comment: Got latest this morning and it works like a champ! Thank you again.